# mysql - make query returns empty string value instead of empty result set for nested query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT value FROM table_a WHERE link_id = (SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE col_id=1 and somefield='some_text')) as item1,

(SELECT value FROM table_a WHERE link_id = (SELECT id FROM table_c WHERE col_id=7 and somefield='some_other_text')) as item2,

(SELECT value FROM table_a WHERE link_id = (SELECT id FROM table_m WHERE col_id=121 and somefield='more_text')) as item3
)
```

if all the inner selects return something everything works ok, however if one of the inner selects does not return something then the whole query does not return anything.

is there anything I can add to the query so that if one of the inner selects does not return something then an empty string is returned in its place?

so for example the first query might return value = 'returning value a' the second might return 'value b' and then the third would return '' i.e. an empty string as no row was found. This would then return a results set with 3 columns -

```
'returning value a' ,'value b',''
```

The whole point of this query is that I want a result set which returns values from a number of differnet tables.  These inner selects are dynamically created from php based on parameters so they will be any number of different options.

If the query can be better written I am happy to change it as long as i get a result set with the the value from each of the inner selects or an empty string if the select does not return anything

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, because your queries seem so messed up!? It doesn't make much sense, you already know the id, from `table_b`, why are you fetching the record again from that?

Comment: Then provide us with a fully detailed to the point query so we can understand what exactly you want to achieve, and maybe provide a better way to do it. Or just come up with what you want. The query you have provided doesn't make much sense, because it can be accomplished in a much simpler one.

Comment: I've rewrote the question hopefully this will explain the probloem better

Comment: Still, your question does not provide enough code to let us understand where you want to go. Your query doesn't make sense, yet. You know the `id`, yet, you go on and fetch it from another table. Please provide a sample of the query from your application, but with table names and columns changed for obscurity.

Comment: the query above is the query i am runnning with table names and columns changes. although I have made another amendment in that i don't know id, the where clause should have been col_id which I have now changed. All I want is a single row returned where each value from the inner select is placed in its own column unless no value is returned in which case i just want an empty string in the column.  so for example if there were 4 inner selects a row would be returned with 4 columns each one with a value. if there were 10 inner selects there would be 10 columns each with a value.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this:

```
SELECT `table_b`.* FROM `table_b`
LEFT JOIN `table_a` ON (`table_b`.`id`=`table_a`.`link_id`)
WHERE `table_a`.`link_id` IN (1,2,3);
```

With `LEFT JOIN` table_b would return fields with `null` values.

Comment: Ok I saw your comment to your question a little too late. Did you try to use "mysql stored procedures"?

Comment: thanks for the answer but the query i have is a little more complicated than the one i put in the example (my fault). I was trying to simplify it but by doing so removed another problem which is that table_b is not just one table but a number of differnet tables so can't just do a join like you suggest. see my comment above. Thanks for the help and if you have any other suggestions I'd be happy to see them

Comment: I go the feeling you have to rethink your problem a little bit and use stored procedures or just explain your problem a better way! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not helping us help you by providing a detailed query, however based on your code, this is what I could come up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ta1.colName item1, ta2.colName item2, ta3.colName item3
           FROM table_a ta1
      LEFT JOIN table_a ta2 
             ON ta2.link_id = (
                                SELECT id 
                                  FROM table_c 
                                 WHERE col_id = 7 
                                   AND somefield = 'some_other_text'
                              )
      LEFT JOIN table_a ta3 
             ON ta3.link_id = (
                                SELECT id 
                                  FROM table_m 
                                 WHERE col_id = 121 
                                   AND somefield = 'more_text'
                               )
          WHERE ta1.link_id = (
                                SELECT id 
                                  FROM table_b 
                                 WHERE col_id = 1 
                                   AND somefield = 'some_text'
                               )
```

You can do this with `LEFT JOIN`s only, if you would like to, but I added in the `WHERE` clause not to waste a table lookup.

Ask me about anything that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but it should do the job:

```
SELECT
    item1.value,
    item2.value,
    item3.value
FROM 
    (
        (SELECT value FROM table_a WHERE link_id = (SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE col_id=1 and somefield='some_text')) as item1 
        RIGHT JOIN (SELECT NULL) t1 ON TRUE
    ),
    (
        (SELECT value FROM table_a WHERE link_id = (SELECT id FROM table_c WHERE col_id=7 and somefield='some_other_text')) as item2
        RIGHT JOIN (SELECT NULL) t2 ON TRUE
    ),
    (
        (SELECT id FROM table_m WHERE col_id=121 and somefield='more_text')) as item3
        RIGHT JOIN (SELECT NULL) t3 ON TRUE
    )
```